# Getting org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [byte]

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am using spring boot + redis database + 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis' in my project.

My repo class has this method accountRepository.findAllByBankId(bankIds) here bankIds is a List. These bankIds are not the main id field which is supposed to get all the records based on these keys. I am getting following err on this line:

org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [byte] for value 'Account:bankId:60:01:XYZ'.

Googled a lot but could not resolve it. Also created this class:

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
public class RedisStringToBytesConverter implements Converter<String, byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] convert(String source) {
        return source.getBytes();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.